# watch the selected value of dropdown with angularjs to populate an array depends on the selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, filter

I have this fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheko_elanteko/Anj3w/9/)

I want to check for the selected value of the model "sectionSelect", and based on the selected value, weather it's "1" or "2", I want to fill the newArr with the new values that match the selected, in order to filter the min and max prices accordingly.

What I'm doing right now is this ...

```
if ($scope.sectionSelect == 1) {

    for($i=0; $i < arr.length; $i++){

        if(arr[$i]['section'] === 1) {
            newArr.push(arr[$i]['value']);
        }
    }

} else if($scope.sectionSelect == 2) {
    for($i=0; $i < arr.length; $i++){

        if(arr[$i]['section'] === 2) {
            newArr.push(arr[$i]['value']);
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
What should I do?

This is what I have and it's working http://jsfiddle.net/sheko_elanteko/Anj3w/26/
I just want to add the filter functionality to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to filter things using Angular is to use the built in filtering capabilities.  I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CQyTa/

The changes to the html use the dropdowns to set scope values for what is selected.  These values can then be used as filters (in this instance, I'm filtering the min and max values based on the which section is selected).

```
<select ng-model="sectionSelect" ng-options="section.label for section in sections" ng-change="clearMinMax()">
</select>
<select ng-model="minVal" ng-options="item.value for item in app_data | filter:sectionSelect.section | orderBy:'value'">
    <option value="">Min Price</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="maxVal" ng-options="item.value for item in app_data | filter: sectionSelect.section | orderBy:'-value'">
    <option value="">Max Price</option>
</select>
```

Based on what is selected in those dropdowns, you can these use all of those to filter what should show up.  The minMax function is in the controller, it just checks whether the value is between the min & max.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in app_data | filter:sectionSelect.section | filter:minMax | orderBy:'value'">
    {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks, but the fiddle doesn't seem to be updated :(

Comment: That's good and everything, but the idea is that I want to add this filter functionality to the "filter price range" functionality that I already have.
That's what I have right now http://jsfiddle.net/sheko_elanteko/Anj3w/26/

I want to add to this what array should feed the price range depends on what user select "For Sale" or "For Rent"

Comment: @Shaker I updated your fiddle to do what you're looking for (http://jsfiddle.net/sf7CT/)  I also updated my original solution to match this functionality (http://jsfiddle.net/CQyTa/).  I feel like that solution is much better as all the functions are contained in the controller, you're not creating/updating multiple arrays, it's just using filters on the whole data source.  With that said, I made your solution work, it could be better with some more cleaning up, but I think it's the wrong direction.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I agree, your approach is better.
Thanks, mate.